# how to resolve apache common-vfs URL encode error

Tags: java, ftp, encode

I use Apache common-vfs to perform FTP operations.But If there is Chinese in URL, some strange questions will arise..

and my code is like this :

```
String path = "ftp://user:pwd@localhost:21/foo/泰聚/说愚惭/询回撼舆/米曲浓树疚/窃窃尿押疆腔/bar";
String encodedPath = new String(path.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
manager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject fo = manager.resolveFile(encodedPath);
fo.createFolder();
```

and the Exception is like this :

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not create FTP directory "ftp://test:***@localhost/test/æ°å¸/éä¸ç»/å¡èåä»»/åªæ²é¡¹æ å/ä¾©èæè¨ç­ç¾".
```

This exception does not appear every time, it appears to be due to the encoding of some words。